# what's the difference between webView.load(QUrl) and QNetworkAccessManager.get(Qurl) in QT?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

UPDATE:I use javaScriptConsoleMessage and got a message on there sites:

```
Can't find variable: jQuery
```

I use PyQt on my project。
Today I want to change the web access way from webView.load(QUrl) to QNetworkAccessManager.get(Qurl)，because webView.load(QUrl) can't use async.

just like below：

before:

```
 self.webView.load(QUrl(input_url))
```

after:

```
AM = QNetworkAccessManager(parent=self)
self.net_reply= AM.get(net_requests)
AM.finished.connect(self.setweb)

def setweb(self, netreply):
    replyArray = netreply.readAll()
    self.qwebView.page().mainFrame().setContent(replyArray )
```

After changed,It work well in most websites, but in some websites(eg, http://www.china.com.cn) the view is not so good ,just like they dont have a css style.How can I change the code to get the right view like webView.load(QUrl)?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is with `setContent()` not being able to load external resources (like CSS) because you're not using the `baseUrl` parameter to tell `QWebView` where to make external requests from.  You can also use [`QWebView::setHtml(...)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebview.html#setHtml) as a shortcut to not set the MIME type as in `setContent()`.